# Is there a way to access the original attributes of a ckeditor element?

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, ckeditor

I'm creating a plugin for CKEditor by tweaking the existing 'Image' plugin so it better suits our purpose.

An issue with it is that it tends to mess around with the existing attributes if you edit an image. For example, anything with a left or right 'align=' attribute gets changed to a 'float:' style after the image has been edited, even if you don't make any changes. Also, anything set to 'auto' is also removed.

With normal html, this isn't a problem but we are creating responsive emails and these attributes are needed to get them to display correctly in Outlook.

I'm trying to make it keep certain attributes based on their original values which are working well. However, I've run into an issue with the 'margin' attribute.

An image in one of our email templates has the margin: style attribute set to '0 auto'. CKEditor seems to process all the Html into a DOM structure with added IDs which it stores and works from - however by the time this value has been processed and included in this internal DOM, it's been changed into

```
margin: "0px"
margin-top: "0px"
margin-bottom: "0px"
margin-left: "0px"
margin-right: "0px"
```

with no sign of the original 'auto' value.

Is there any way to access the original un-DOMed HTML string of the element so I can retrieve the original style property?

I've poked about inside both the dialog and the CKEDITOR object; I've found that the CKEDITOR object does store the 'raw' DOM structure itself with the unprocessed style attribute, however short of some hideously complicated traversal of this I can't find a way of referencing back to the element within this unprocessed DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

The Dialog object holds an object called 'cleanImageElement'. This contains the unmolested style attribute from where I can read the style tag I need.